# AS 2.0 classes can't access their own height or width?

Tags: flash, oop, actionscript-2

I am working with some Flash banners and I haven't touched ActionScript classes in a while, and this is probably my first time writing in AS 2.0 classes. I just tried this:

```
class AdPage {

    public function AdPage() {
        trace("AdPage added to stage.");
            trace( this._width );
    }

}
```

and the compiler seems to have broken. It stops processing at the constructor and I never see a trace of the MovieClip's width. I thought, "OK, well the constructor is just too fast." and took it out and tried the same code in a function outside the constructor. But it still crashes the compiler. Is this a thing in Flash? You can't get a MovieClip's height or width from inside itself (well, technically, from inside its own class)? You have to get it from something outside the instance?

Thanks!

Comment: Your class isn't extending `MovieClip`, so where would the height/width come from?

Comment: OH MY GOD YOU'RE RIGHT

If you make this into an answer, I'll check it. Thanks!
Update: ....in nine minutes, apparently, after SO lets me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want AdPage to be a MovieClip, you need to base it on MovieClip;

```
class AdPage extends MovieClip {
```